# How can I merge two Scala (String, String) for Play! query strings?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

The end goal is to connect two query parameters that are being passed to a Play! web service request. It looks like:

```
WS
.url(requestUri)
.withQueryString(finalQueries)
```

I attempted to use a couple operators but it failed like so:

```
val finalQueries = queryParams match {
        case Some(queries) =>
          tokenParam ++ queries
        case None =>
          tokenParam
}
```

**Error:** `value ++ is not a member of (String, String)`

The API documentation shows that `withQueryString` accepts a `(String, String)*`

I'm a little confused with Play!'s `withQueryString` method since it does appear to complete replace the entire query string every time I access it. Any way to decently combine query strings?

**Edit:** A sample query string is below (the type syntax and its final appearance are a little confusing...):

`val queryString = ("timeMin" -> "2012-08-20T01%3A11%3A06.000Z")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from your code, it seems to me that `queryParams` should be `Option[(String, String)]`, and from the error message, `tokenParam` must be `(String, String)`
I think you can try this:

```
val finalQueries = Seq(tokenParam) ++ queryParams
WS
.url(requestUri)
.withQueryString(finalQueries:_*)
```

---

it works because `Option` can be treated as `Seq`, eg: `Seq(1, 2) ++ Some(3)` will become `Seq(1, 2, 3)` and `Seq(1, 2) ++ None` will be just `Seq(1, 2)`

and then `.withQueryString` accepts a `(String, String)*` means you can call it like `.withQueryString(param1, param2, andMore)`,
or you can call it with a `Seq` and tell the compiler to treat it like *anythingRepeated* by writing `: _*` at the end of the `Seq` like `.withQueryString(Seq(param1, param2, andMore): _*)`

Comment: My bad for not adding a sample of the final string, I've put it in there! this did the trick, and thanks for explaining it as well. i was unaware of the nifty `:_*`